# get path from Google Drive URI

Tags: android, uri, filepath, google-drive-android-api

I'm using Android file selection and selecting files from app storage (images, videos, documents). I have an function "getPath" . Im getting path from uri. I have no problem with gallery images or download documents. But when i select a file from google drive i cant get path. This is the google drive uri "content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D25%3Bdoc%3D12" 
Can you help me about it ?

This is also my "getPath" function.

```
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    // check here to KITKAT or new version
    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {

        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                        + split[1];
            }
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"),
                    Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { split[1] };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection,
                    selectionArgs);
        }
        else if(isGoogleDriveUri(uri)){
                //Get google drive path here

        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

        // Return the remote address
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return nopath;
}

public static String iStreamToString(InputStream is1)
{
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is1), 4096);
    String line;
    StringBuilder sb =  new StringBuilder();
    try {
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        rd.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String contentOfMyInputStream = sb.toString();
    return contentOfMyInputStream;
}
```

Comment: you got solution for this?

Comment: Any Solution for this ?

Answer (score 17):

```
Get file path from Google Drive we can easily access by Using File Provider by using following steps Code is working fine.

1) Add provider path in AndroidManifest file inside Applcation Tag.
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.satya.filemangerdemo.activity.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
    </application>


2) provider_paths.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <cache-path
        name="my_cache"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>

3)FileUtils.java

public class FileUtils {
    private static Uri contentUri = null;
 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
        // check here to KITKAT or new version
        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri))
          {
            / MediaProvider
             if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                 if (isGoogleDriveUri(uri)) {
                return getDriveFilePath(uri, context);
            }


          }
      }

4) isGoogleDriveUri method 

  private static boolean isGoogleDriveUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.docs.storage".equals(uri.getAuthority()) || "com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

5)getDriveFilePath method 
 private static String getDriveFilePath(Uri uri, Context context) {
        Uri returnUri = uri;
        Cursor returnCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(returnUri, null, null, null, null);
        /*
         * Get the column indexes of the data in the Cursor,
         *     * move to the first row in the Cursor, get the data,
         *     * and display it.
         * */
        int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
        returnCursor.moveToFirst();
        String name = (returnCursor.getString(nameIndex));
        String size = (Long.toString(returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex)));
        File file = new File(context.getCacheDir(), name);
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            int read = 0;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
            int bytesAvailable = inputStream.available();

            //int bufferSize = 1024;
            int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);

            final byte[] buffers = new byte[bufferSize];
            while ((read = inputStream.read(buffers)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffers, 0, read);
            }
            Log.e("File Size", "Size " + file.length());
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
            Log.e("File Path", "Path " + file.getPath());
            Log.e("File Size", "Size " + file.length());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
        }
        return file.getPath();
    }
```

Comment: above code is working we can get file path from google drive add permission manifest     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />

Comment: I can't see why you are saying `by Using File Provider`? You are not using a `FileProvider`.

Comment: This is quite useful. Thanks for it. I'm having a requirement to select multiple images at a time from google drive. Is it feasible to do so? If yes, how to get it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For multi-selection of media, we need to add property intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true); while setting the intent.
For ref.
'Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);'
& in onActivityForResult(..) method, use ClipData to get uri of all selected images.

Answer (score 13):

> I have no problem with gallery images or download documents

You will, on many devices.

> But when i select a file from google drive i cant get path

There is no path. `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` does not allow the user to choose a file. It allows the user to choose a piece of content. That content *might* be a local file. That content might also be:

- Something [on a file server on the network](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.sambadocumentsprovider)
- Something in a cloud storage service, such as Google Drive, and therefore is not on the device at the moment
- Something in [an encrypted volume](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/android-5.0.0_r2/samples/Vault/)
- Something that *is* a file, but is not a file that you can access directly, such as from [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) of another app
- And so on

You have two main options. If you *only* want *files*, then use [a third-party file chooser library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35) to replace all of the code in your question.

Or, if you still want to use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, you can take the `Uri` that you get from `data.getData()` in `onActivityResult()` and do two things with it:

- First, use `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri()` to get a `DocumentFile` object pointing to that `Uri`. You can call `getName()` on the `DocumentFile` to get a "display name" for the content, which should be something that the user will recognize.
- Then, use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get at the content itself, similar to how you might use a `FileInputStream` to get at the bytes in a file.

Comment: after getting inputstream what to do?

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan: Read in the bytes. Then, do something with those bytes. What "do something" is depends a lot on the content and what your app's functionality is.

Comment: Future readers, https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider

Answer (score 6):

I was also stuck with the same issue and found that when we choose image from google drive its uri is like below

```
com.google.android.apps.docs.storage
```

and we cant directly get the path of file as it is not in our device. So we first download the file to a certain destination and then we can use that path to do our work. Below is the code for the same

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
         fos = new FileOutputStream(getDestinationFilePath());
         try (BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(fos); 
         InputStream in = mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)) 
           {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            int len = 0;

            while ((len = in.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                  out.write(buffer, 0, len);
                 }

             out.flush();
            } finally {
                       fos.getFD().sync();
                      }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

            File file = new File(destinationFilePath);
            if (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(file.length() / 1024)) > 1024) {
            InputStream imageStream = null;



            try {
                 imageStream = mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

now your file is saved at the desired destination path and you can use it.

Comment: Can you please explain this ? What is getDestinationFilePath()?

Comment: getDestinationFilePath() is the new path where you will write the file.