# Unable to load image into imageview from GoogleStorageURI (Google Drive image uri) using Gallery Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, imageview, android-gallery

I have downloaded an image from Google Drive storage. I want to set this image to imageview in my app using Gallery Intent.

Uri of image received in onActivityResult: content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D2%3Bdoc%3Dencoded%3DWe%2BdXDcNgTeulVk1Ntu3YfRYkm9wk7uTdTG6LFVyck1BxY4g7xAxyPAgtMtz4A%3D%3S

I am using this code get the real-path from the url:

```
 if ("com.google.android.apps.docs.storage".equals(uri
                    .getAuthority())) {

    //content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D2%3Bdoc%3Dencoded%3DWe%2BdXDcNbYeulVk1Ntu3YfRYkm9wk7uTdTG6LE6yck1BxY4g7xAxyPAgtMtz4A%3D%3D

 final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                    final String id = docId.split(";")[1];
                    final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{id};
                    //String[] column = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};


                    // where id is equal to
                    String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";
                    Uri contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

                    //..
                    Cursor cursor = null;
                    String filePath = null;
                    try {
                        String[] column = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,
                                column, selection, selectionArgs, null);
                        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);
                            filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                        }
                    } finally {
                        if (cursor != null)
                            cursor.close();

                        return filePath;


 }
            }
```

.....

But I am getting NULL cursor. Thus, filepath is always empty/null.

Anyone, could please suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I got its working solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54762441/5582162 .

Answer (score 0):

> I am using this code get the real-path from the url

Delete it.

> Anyone, could please suggest what I am doing wrong?

You are using that code.

Pass the `Uri` to your favorite image-loading library (Glide, Picasso, etc.). It will do all the work for you, populating your `ImageView`, in just a few lines of code.

Or, if you insist on doing it yourself:

- Use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`
- Use `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` to get a `Bitmap` based on that `InputStream`
- Do those two steps on a background thread, as you should not do disk I/O and image decoding on the main application thread
- On the main application thread, put the `Bitmap` in your `ImageView`,

Comment: Thanks, @CommonsWare. I will try what you suggested.